# simple_html_dom parsing question with data attributes

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have been struggling with this problem for some time. I am trying to parse an html document that has many div tags, inside those div tags are other div tags that have some data attributes that I need to parse.

I do however need to keep the original loop of the div class="row".  this cannot change.

```
    $test_html = '
        <div class="row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo1" data-op-source="somesource1" data-op-status="some status">some content 1</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo2">some content b</div>
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo3" data-op-status="somemoney3" data-op-source="somesource3">some content 3</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo4">some content 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo1" data-op-source="somesource1" data-op-status="some status">some content 1</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo2">some content b</div>
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo3" data-op-status="somemoney3" data-op-source="somesource3">some content 3</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo4">some content 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo1" data-op-source="somesource1" data-op-status="some status">some content 1</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo2">some content b</div>
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo3" data-op-status="somemoney3" data-op-source="somesource3">some content 3</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo4">some content 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo1" data-op-source="somesource1" data-op-status="some status">some content 1</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo2">some content b</div>
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo3" data-op-status="somemoney3" data-op-source="somesource3">some content 3</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo4">some content 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo1" data-op-source="somesource1" data-op-status="some status">some content 1</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo2">some content b</div>
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo3" data-op-status="somemoney3" data-op-source="somesource3">some content 3</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo4">some content 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo1" data-op-source="somesource1" data-op-status="some status">some content 1</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo2">some content b</div>
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo3" data-op-status="somemoney3" data-op-source="somesource3">some content 3</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo4">some content 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo1" data-op-source="somesource1" data-op-status="some status">some content 1</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo2">some content b</div>
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo3" data-op-status="somemoney3" data-op-source="somesource3">some content 3</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo4">some content 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo1" data-op-source="somesource1" data-op-status="some status">some content 1</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo2">some content b</div>
                <div class="op-item op-spread" data-op-info="someinfo3" data-op-status="somemoney3" data-op-source="somesource3">some content 3</div>
                <div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info="someinfo4">some content 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        '; 

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($test_html, true, false);

    foreach($html->find('div.row') as $a) {

        $item['book']['data'] = $a->find('div.item',0)->outertext;
        $item['book']['div1']['data-op-info'] = "someinfo1"; // desired output
        $item['book']['div2']['data-op-info'] = "someinfo2"; // desired output
        $item['book']['div3']['data-op-info'] = "someinfo3"; // desired output
        $item['book']['div4']['data-op-info'] = "someinfo4"; // desired output

        //$item['book']['div1'] = $a->find('div.item',1)->outertext;
        //$item['book']['div2'] = $a->find('div.item',2)->outertext;
        //$item['book']['div3'] = $a->find('div.item',3)->outertext;

    $data[] = $item;

    }

    print_r($data);
```

I hope someone is able to help me out, been trying to wrap my head around this for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

You can query children nodes on your `item` node and use the function `getAttribute()` to have what you need.

Here, I assume the nodes are always in the same order. Maybe you need to change the selector to something more specific :

```
$itemNode = $a->find('div.item',0) ;

$item['book']['data'] = $itemNode->outertext;
$item['book']['div1']['data-op-info'] = $itemNode->find('div.op-item',0)->getAttribute('data-op-info') ;
$item['book']['div2']['data-op-info'] = $itemNode->find('div.op-item',1)->getAttribute('data-op-info');
$item['book']['div3']['data-op-info'] = $itemNode->find('div.op-item',2)->getAttribute('data-op-info');
$item['book']['div4']['data-op-info'] = $itemNode->find('div.op-item',3)->getAttribute('data-op-info');
```